# Mongodb aggregation taking more than 15 seconds

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have more than 100k records in my collections, and for every 5 seconds it will add a record into collection. I have a aggregate query to get 720(approx) records from last one year data.

The aggregate query:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {"$match": {
        "Id": "****-id-****",
        "receivedDate": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2016-06-26T18:30:00.463Z"), 
            "$lt": ISODate("2017-06-26T18:30:00.463Z")
        }
    }
    },
    {"$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$add": [
                {"$subtract": [
                    {"$subtract": ["$receivedDate", ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")]},
                    {"$mod": [
                        {"$subtract": ["$receivedDate", ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")]},
                    43200000
                    ]}
                ]},
                    ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
            ]
        }, 
        "_rid": {"$first": "$_id"}, 
        "_data": {"$first": "$receivedData.data"}, 
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }
    },
    {"$sort": {"_id": -1}},
    {"$project": {
        "_id": "$_rid", 
        "receivedDate": "$_id", 
        "receivedData": {"data": "$_data"}
    }
    }
])
```

I am not sure why its taking more than 15 seconds, when I try to get data for 1 month it is working fine.

Comment: Where is the index? Is there an index on the `"receivedDate"` at all? Also what is `"Id"`? And is there an index on that? If you need it then there should be a compound index on that as well as the date. 100,000 is a bit, but it's not really a lot, so either hardware is extremely under-powered. How many months are you trying to run over? The output is at 12 hour intervals, so I cannot see that really anything more than 1 month at a time has a lot of use, since it's simply a lot of data. Also don't do things like `$project` after a `$group`. It's just wasting cycles and time. Live with it.

Comment: yes, `receivedDate` has an index, and Id is the device Id from where I will get data for every 5 seconds, there are multiple devices connected to app.

Answer (score 0):

Its too late to answer this question, This would be helpful for others,

Might be the [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) can help in this situation, Compound indexes can support queries that match on multiple fields.

You can create compound index on `Id` and `receivedDate` fields,

```
db.collectionName.createIndex({ Id: -1, receivedDate: -1 });
```

The order of the fields listed in a compound index is important. The index will contain references to documents sorted first by the values of the `Id` field and, within each value of the `Id` field, sorted by values of the `receivedDate` field.